# Dagger 2 LocalDataSource cannot be provided without @Provides annotated method

Tags: java, android, dependency-injection, dagger-2, dagger

I'm trying to follow the same example as in [here](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture/tree/todo-mvp-dagger) by creating a Repository pattern with DI.
The problem is that I get the following error:

> "Error:(16, 20) error: @mvp.model.di.scope.Local
>   mvp.model.repository.local.GameLocalDataSource cannot be provided
>   without an @Provides-annotated method. @mvp.model.di.scope.Local
>   mvp.model.repository.local.GameLocalDataSource is injected at
>   mvp.model.repository.GameRepository.(gameLocalDataSource, …)
>   mvp.model.repository.GameRepository is provided at
>   mvp.model.di.component.RepositoryComponent.getGameRepository()"

Here's the code related to the app:

```
public class GameApplication extends Application {
private RepositoryComponent repositoryComponent;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    if (LeakCanary.isInAnalyzerProcess(this)) {
        // This process is dedicated to LeakCanary for heap analysis.
        // You should not init your app in this process.
        return;
    }
    LeakCanary.install(this);
    // Normal app init code...
    repositoryComponent = DaggerRepositoryComponent.builder()
            .applicationModule(new ApplicationModule((getApplicationContext())))
            .build();
}

public RepositoryComponent getRepositoryComponent() {
    return repositoryComponent;
}
}
```

This is my `RepositoryComponent`:

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = {RepositoryModule.class, ApplicationModule.class})
public interface RepositoryComponent {
    GameRepository getGameRepository();
}
```

Here's the `RepositoryModule`:

```
    @Module
public class RepositoryModule {
    @Singleton
    @Provides
    @Local
    GameDataSource provideLocalDataSource(Context context) {
        return new GameLocalDataSource(context);
    }

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    @Remote
    GameDataSource provideRemoteDataSource() {
        return new GameRemoteDataSource();
    }
}
```

And finally, the `ApplicationModule`:

```
    @Module
public final class ApplicationModule {
    private Context context;

    public ApplicationModule(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Provides
    Context providesContext() {
        return context;
    }
}
```

Here's most of my `GameRepository` class:

```
@Singleton
public class GameRepository implements GameDataSource {
    private GameDataSource remoteDataSource;
    private GameDataSource localDataSource;

    @Inject
    public GameRepository(@Local GameLocalDataSource gameLocalDataSource, @Remote GameRemoteDataSource gameRemoteDataSource) {
        remoteDataSource = gameRemoteDataSource;
        localDataSource = gameLocalDataSource;
    }
```

Also, as in the mentioned example, I created a couple of scopes, `@Local` and `@Remote` since my two data sources have the same type and Dagger needs to differentiate them.

```
@Qualifier
@Documented
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface Local {

}
```

The rest of the code I have related to dagger, is just the `@Inject` in the constructors where I want to inject my dependencies.
Also, the `DaggerRepositoryComponent` is never generated in the `GameApplication` class.

Thanks a lot for the help in advance!

Comment: please post the class that use use @Inject GameLocalDataSource

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> GameLocalDataSource cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method

Somewhere in the code you are trying to `@Inject` `GameLocalDataSource`, but you have specified in your module how to provide `GameDataSource`, **not** `GameLocalDataSource`.

```
...
GameDataSource provideLocalDataSource(Context context) {
    return new GameLocalDataSource(context);
}
...
```

Either ask Dagger to inject `GameDataSource`, or describe Dagger how to provide `GameLocalDataSource`.

```
...
GameLocalDataSource provideLocalDataSource(Context context) {
    return new GameLocalDataSource(context);
}
...
```

Comment: indeed that was the problem! lots of hours looking at the components and my brain obviously overlooked at that tiny but very important detail. Thanks a lot!